# How to properly manipulate LCN Stock Market

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I read a guide somewhere on a method to manipulate the LCN stock market within the game. The steps were as follows:

1. Save the game
2. Open the LCN stock market page
3. Screenshot each price in the stock market
4. Save the game (A)
5. Sleep
6. Open the LCN stock market page
7. Screenshot each price in the stock market
8. Determine which stock would result in the highest profit
9. Load Save (A)
10. Dump all of the money into the stock selected from 8
11. Sleep
12. Sell all stock you just bought.

The premise is that you'll know which stock will give you the most amount of money in the future, so you know where to invest it. This does not take into consideration any personal impact you product on the world.

To aid in this, I made a spreadsheet where I could put in the *pre* price, *post* price, and starting funds, and it will spit out which stock will net the highest profit.

The problem though is that it's not working. Specifically, I can follow each of these steps, and when I go to sell the stocks (after knowing which one nets the most) the price is different, and usually results in a net loss.

Am I missing something during this process? Was this fixed to make the stocks random, outside of player intervention?

Answer (score -1):

I promise this works.

1. Stay by your bed and first save game.
2. Invest all of your money in 1 stock ( I suggest it to be at least 20 million or itll take forever.
3. Sleep about 1 to 2 in day games, you can always reload if you waited to long.
4. Sell your stock and save game.
5. Reload your most recent game from step 4.
6. The stock you invested in should be low again so repeat process.

I've made 6 million in about 10 to 15 minutes. The more money you can invest the higher the payout. And works as of 10/20/2019

Answer (score -2):

Stocks are random so this doesn't work.

Comment: Reviewers: Please be aware that this is an answer to the question. Read the question more closely if you're not sure why.